# GEOS segmentation fault when loading libc.so.6

Tags: python, shapely, geos

I'm trying to run a program that uses shapely on a GCE Virtual Machine (Ubuntu 18.04). I'm getting an error on the `geos.py` file, here is the relevant trace I'm getting:

```
[geos:73] - [DEBUG]: Found GEOS DLL: <CDLL '/home/loic/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/shapely/.libs/libgeos_c-5031f9ac.so.1.13.1', handle 31283c0 at 0x7f5aefc58940>, using it.
[geos:38] - [DEBUG]: Trying `CDLL(libc.so.6)`
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm running this program inside a python virtualenv, with `Shapely==1.7.0`. The thing is, when I'm launching this program locally, with basically the same environment, I'm not getting any error, `CDLL(libc.so.6)` is working fine.

Here's the output of `ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep libc`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2030544 Apr 16  2018 libc-2.27.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      12 Apr 16  2018 libc.so.6 -> libc-2.27.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Sep 24  2017 libcap-ng.so.0 -> libcap-ng.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   18712 Sep 24  2017 libcap-ng.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 Nov 16  2017 libcap.so.2 -> libcap.so.2.25
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   22768 Nov 16  2017 libcap.so.2.25
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  190784 Apr 16  2018 libcidn-2.27.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Apr 16  2018 libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.27.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Jan 22 14:40 libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14248 Jan 22 14:40 libcom_err.so.2.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   39208 Apr 16  2018 libcrypt-2.27.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Apr 16  2018 libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.27.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      23 Aug 23  2018 libcryptsetup.so.12 -> libcryptsetup.so.12.2.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  310040 Aug 23  2018 libcryptsetup.so.12.2.0
```

Has anyone experienced this before, or know how to fix this issue? I can provide more information if needed.